# A word for a failure to keep up-to-date

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to think if there's a word for a failure to keep up-to-date. For example, the British NHS's recent well-documented failure to maintain Windows XP, or a professional's failure to maintain Continuing Professional Development.

E.g.

"I'm not sure that your [delinquency] is our problem."

'Delinquency' may in fact be the best word, but I had in my mind something more akin to reprobation - I just can't quite put my finger on it, if indeed there is an 'it' to begin with.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Do you need a noun, verb, or adjective? Or does it not matter?

Comment: Please include an example sentence showing how you would use the word, with something like a ___ where you want the target word to go. This helps us understand what kind of word and associations you want, so you get better answers. (It's also technically required for single-word-requests.)

Comment: In a informal way people often say they were "lagging" on a responsibility.  "lagging" comes close to "procrastinating" but it is a bit less deliberate avoidance with a stronger sense of laziness.

Comment: Consider 'Negligence?' -- "You should have kept yourself up-to-date; I'm not sure that your *negligence* is our problem." Considering their meanings, 'delinquency' and 'reprobate' are not suitable in this context.

Comment: Lack of vigilance or [absentmindedness](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/absentmindedness)

Comment: @EnglishStudent You should make that an answer.

Comment: @1006a the only reason I didn't make it an answer is that '**negligence**' is a generic word that can be applied to many things, whereas OP wants a single word that means "***neglect to keep up-to-date***."

Comment: @EnglishStudent I don't think there's a better term, though. The OP asked for ***failure** to keep up to date* and I suspect you can find a definition of *neglect* that is very similar (*failure to take proper care* or thereabouts).

Comment: @1006a you are right from the language point of view.  However OP was possibly asking from a technical / technological perspective and has already accepted the word 'obsolescence' suggested by Clare in the below answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

obsolescence

> The process or fact of becoming obsolete or outdated, or of falling into disuse

(*Oxford English Dictionary*)

> The process of becoming obsolete or outdated and no longer used

(Oxford online dictionary)

Comment: Links that are clickable are most welcome, it means that users can check the definitions for themselves. Yes, the first link requires that you have a subscription but the second dictionary definition is from a free source.

Comment: Oh, I like obsolescence. That fits very well.

Answer (score -1):

Out-of-date. Or  old-fashioned

Comment: Nourhan, welcome to the site and thanks for participating.  As you find your way around here, you'll see that documentation strengthens answers.  Tip: if you want to share a quick thought, try putting it in a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Note that the two suggestions you offer—although they provide reasonable answers to the broader question implied by the header "A word for failure to keep up-to-date"—would not work as fill-in-the-blank replacements for _delinquency_ in the sentence "I'm not sure that your [delinquency] is our problem." Since that is the sense of "failure to keep up-to-date" that the poster is interested in, your answer isn't on point.

Answer (score -1):

### Deprecated

> to withdraw official support for or discourage the use of
> (something, such as a software product) in favor of a newer or better
> alternative

*(Merriam-Webster (online))*

`The tech writers released version 2 of the user manual; version 1 is now deprecated.`

---

Comment: I don't think that deprecated, while related, actually describes a failure to keep up to date.